# How to split the Excel file that contains multiple sheets?

Tags: php, excel

I have the Excel file that contains a few sheets. How to split this file to get get each sheet as a separate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP, you'llneed to have something like [phpExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to open the spreadsheet, and rewrite each tab as a new file.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) library:

```
include 'PHPExcel.php';

$fileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'testExcel.xlsx';

$objPHPExcelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcelReader->load($inputFileName);

$sheetIndex = 0;
$sheetCount = $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount();
while ($sheetIndex < $sheetCount) {
    ++$sheetIndex;
    $workSheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);

    $newObjPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $newObjPHPExcel->removeSheetByIndex(0);
    $newObjPHPExcel->addExternalSheet($workSheet);

    $objPHPExcelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($newObjPHPExcel,$fileType);
    $outputFileTemp = explode('.',$inputFileName);
    $outputFileName = $outputFileTemp[0].$sheetIndex.'.'.$outputFileTemp[1];
    $objPHPExcelWriter->save($outputFileName);
}
```